# Does calling a read function with input leave any trace?

Tags: transactions, nodes, geth-debugging

I want to call a read function which does a calculation and returns a result. It is important that the input will not be saved on the blockchain.
If I were to use a write function then even if there isn't a state change (i.e., I don't save a variable) the transaction will forever be present on the blockchain with the secret input.
How does it work with read a call? I'm confident that it isn't a transaction and does not propagate and thus does not remains on the blockchain. Is it running by the node I communicate with and leaves no trace then? and if so is it stored in some node caching mechanism for a while (e.g., in commonly used software like Geth) and can it be accessed by someone?

Answer (score 1):

You can do calculations, read global variables (not edit), make local variables in a function to be called without showing any trace in blockchain.

When you call read function below, it will not be saved in the blockchain:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract calculate{
    int something=10;
    function read(int a) view public returns(int){
        int square=a*a;
        int cube=square*a;
        return cube*something/10; // round off to integer
    }
}
```

```
// web3JS
var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
MyContract.methods.read(1234).call()
.then(console.log);
```

Also, Float is not allowed in solidity, so if u will use PI(3.14), or want decimal output, then you will get round off integer.

Provide codes in question for detailed answer.